# Functional Dependencies - Finding if F implies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Given the following functional dependencies

```
F = { A -> BC, CD -> E, B -> D, E -> A }
```

I cannot wrap my head that F |= E -> BC is false. If you have E, you can go to A, if you have A, you can go to BC. What is incorrect with this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your logic. F |= E->BC.